# NN training with repetitive features

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, training, features

I posted the question also on [ai.stackexchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/21274/nn-training-with-features-that-are-repeated) but it didn't get any answers so I though I could try here.

Here is a copy paste:

> Let's say you are training a NN in a RL setting where the state (i.e. features/input data) does not change in every step, but rather in a few (~typically around 8 steps).
>
> For example, a state might consist of the following values:
>
> 30, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 0
>
> And then again the same values for 6-7 times more resulting in ultimately the following input arrays:
>
> [[30, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 0], [30, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 0], ..., [30, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 0]]
>
> I know that the value 0 in the feature set depicts that the weight for this feature results in insignificant value.
>
> But what about repetition of values?
>
> How does that affect learning, if it does at all?
>
> Any ideas?
>
> Best, Marios.
>
> Edit: I did not know how to search for this particular topic, it might have been answered >before, maybe you can point me there. Thanks.

***Edit***: I was advised to delete this question and leave it only on AI SE. However, and since I have been upvoted already, people might want to trace it back here for an answer.

Only for that reason, I leave the question here with the link that traces back to the original updated question and accepted answer.